# mutating trigger, when we can read from triggering table and when not?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 triggers, both of them are row level and read data from triggering table. My question is why one of them(trg1) cause MUTATING trigger error and the other(trg2) does not. Why only  one of them can SELECT the triggering table? I know the possibility of autonomous transaction. I only wants to understand the rule when can we read from triggering table and when not.

Triggers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg1
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON employees
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   myval   NUMBER
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO myval
     FROM employees;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg2
BEFORE INSERT ON tab_1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR c IS SELECT * FROM tab_1 WHERE col_1 = :NEW.col_1;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c LOOP
    INSERT INTO tab_2 
    VALUES (:NEW.col_1, :NEW.col_2, NULL );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks,
T

Comment: The error will be in after trigger ,because you are trying to read the table while it is been modified ,the transaction is not yet completed .So in this case oracle is dosent want to read inconsistent data frm the same table which is been modified.while in before trigger nothing is changed and it allows you to read from the table  before doing the dml operation on the table.

Comment: If we change the first trigger to be a BEFORE INSERT, it still remains a mutating trigger.

Comment: are you telling me that ,it is still giving u this error after changing it to before insert trigger?

Comment: Yes, I tried, and it is still mutating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A row-level trigger can read from the table only

- if it is a BEFORE INSERT trigger
- if it is a single-row operation

Therefore, both triggers will raise an ORA-04091 - the AFTER INSERT will always raise one, the BEFORE INSERT only if you try a multi-row INSERT.

Try running this statement:

```
insert into tab_1(col_1, col_2) 
(select 'b', 'seven' from dual union all select 8, 'c', 'eight' from dual);
```

and you'll get an ORA-04091, as well.

See [Database journal article on mutating tables](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3329121/The-Mutation-error-in-Oracle-Database-Triggers.htm) for details

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted.